# Loop from category to sub category in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We are having a structure like the way you are seeing in below screenshot:

[image]

And our database structure looks like this:

[image]

Here in database table "PID" is the Parent ID in which 0 = Parent ID. And rest PID is the parent id of same id.

Now we are trying to get all the sub category of "Brand" Or "Footware" so it should show all (sub-sub-category and sub-sub-sub-category) the sub category details under that tree. Can this be done through PHP? any loop or any way?

Thank you!

Comment: use recursion for this..

Comment: Use `JOIN`s on same table.

Comment: kc1994--what is recursion? any example?

Comment: @user3201500 use left join on the same table reference http://www.roytuts.com/infinite-dynamic-multi-level-nested-category-with-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function fetchCategoryTreeList($parent = 0, $user_tree_array = '') {
global $con;
if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
$user_tree_array = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE 1 AND `parent_id` = $parent ORDER BY id ASC";
$result=$con->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $user_tree_array[] = "<ul>";
 while ($row =$result->fetch_object())
 {
  $user_tree_array[] = "<li>". $row->name."</li>";
      $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTreeList($row->id, $user_tree_array);
 }
 $user_tree_array[] = "</ul><br/>";
}
  return $user_tree_array;
}
```

call function here

```
$res = fetchCategoryTreeList();
foreach ($res as $r)
{
   echo  $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
//connect to mysql and select db
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'rootuser', 'rootpwd','dbname');

if( !empty($conn->connect_errno)) die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));

//call the recursive function to print category listing
category_tree(0);

//Recursive php function
function category_tree($catid){
global $conn;

$sql = "select * from category where pid ='".$catid."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)):
$i = 0;
if ($i == 0) echo '<ul>';
 echo '<li>' . $row->category;
 category_tree($row->id);
 echo '</li>';
$i++;
 if ($i > 0) echo '</ul>';
endwhile;
}
//close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I used this function in my project, it is a recursive function.
>
> /**** GET ALL CATEGORIES FUNCTION  *******/

```
 function categoryChild($id, $spacing = '') {
            $s = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_cat_id = $id ";

            $r = mysql_query($s);

            $children = array();

            if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {

                    $children[$row['category_id']]['category_name'] = $spacing.$row['category_name'];
                    $children[$row['category_id']]['id'] = $row['category_id'];
                    $children[$row['category_id']]['child'] = categoryChild($row['category_id'], $spacing . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
                }
            }

            return $children;
        }


>   /************ GET ALL CATEGORIES FUNCTION****************/
$allcategory =   categoryChild(0);

print_r($allcategory);
```