# How to get all children of category and show them like tree in mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, tree

I have a tree system table in mySql.

It is `categories` table:

<kbd>**`category_id`**</kbd><kbd>**`category_title`**</kbd><kbd>**`category_parent_id`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>          <kbd>`Technologies`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`2`</kbd>          <kbd>`Web`</kbd>           <kbd>`1`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`3`</kbd>          <kbd>`OS`</kbd>            <kbd>`1`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`4`</kbd>          <kbd>`Software`</kbd>      <kbd>`1`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`5`</kbd>          <kbd>`Hardware`</kbd>      <kbd>`1`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`6`</kbd>          <kbd>`PHP`</kbd>           <kbd>`2`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`7`</kbd>          <kbd>`HTML`</kbd>          <kbd>`2`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`8`</kbd>          <kbd>`JavaScrip`</kbd>     <kbd>`2`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`9`</kbd>          <kbd>`Jquery`</kbd>        <kbd>`8`</kbd>                 
<kbd>`10`</kbd>         <kbd>`Angulra.js`</kbd>    <kbd>`8`</kbd>

As you see my data, I have a tree system, I want to have a PHP function or a SQL query to return all children like below:

```
Technologies
Technologies > Web
Technologies > OS
Technologies > Software
Technologies > Hardware
Technologies > Web > PHP
Technologies > Web > HTML
Technologies > Web > JavaScript
Technologies > Web > JavaScript > Jquery
Technologies > Web > JavaScript > Amgular.js
```

Can you help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194671/loop-from-category-to-sub-category-in-php/34194839#34194839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function list_to_tree($list, $pk = 'category_id', $pid = 'category_parent_id', $child = '_child', $root = 0)
{
    $tree = array();
    if (is_array($list))
    {
        $refer = array();
        foreach ($list as $key => $data)
        {
            $refer[$data[$pk]] =& $list[$key];
        }
        foreach ($list as $key => $data)
        {
            $parentId = $data[$pid];
            if ($root == $parentId)
            {
                $tree[] =& $list[$key];
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset($refer[$parentId]))
                {
                    $parent =& $refer[$parentId];
                    $parent[$child][] =& $list[$key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is something best solved in the application, not SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer